# Strange behaviour in Visual Studio IDE after modifying edmx diagram

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 with lot of projects. I have modified the entity model of a project (edmx diagram) but after doing so the edmx is not marked with a red thick indicating it has been modified. Only its files *.Context.tt, *.cs, *.diagram and *.tt are marked with a red thick.

I am wondering if this behaviour is normal. Isn't it?

If I check-in these changes on edmx, what will happen in this state?

Below an image (I have crossed out the file names with blue color for confidentiality):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered why is behaving so. This happens when an item is marked to be deleted.